# Running concurrent CUDA kernels, called from c++ wrapper functions

Tags: c++, concurrency, cuda, pthreads

I have c++ code, that calls CUDA code.    I am using GTX 680 GPU.
Currently it runs like this:

```
fn_1(); //calls CUDA code (indirectly)  
fn_a(); //calls CUDA code (indirectly), must run AFTER fn_1  
fn_2(); //calls CUDA code (indirectly), must run AFTER fn_1  
fn_b(); //calls CUDA code (indirectly), must run AFTER fn_2  
fn_3(); //calls CUDA code (indirectly), must run AFTER fn_2  
fn_c(); //calls CUDA code (indirectly), must run AFTER fn_3
```

and each function is like this:

```
void fn_*(){
    call_cuda_fn_x(); //calls CUDA code
    call_cuda_fn_y(); //calls CUDA code, must run AFTER call_cuda_fn_x
}
```

Some of these functions do NOT fully utilise my GPU  (GTX 680).
Therefore, I would like to have fn_2() and fn_a() run concurrently, then call fn_3() and fn_b() as soon as fn_2() finishes.  Then synchronise everything after calling fn_c().

```
fn_1();  
fn_2();  also launch fn_a()
fn_3();  also launch fn_b()
fn_c();
synchronise() //ensure that fn_a() && fn_b() && fn_c() have finished.
```

Can I do this?  If so, can you sketch out how?

(Note that e.g. fn_b() has several c++ functions inside of it, that must be run sequentially - presumably that means I need to use more than 1 cpu thread, in order to call fn_2() and fn_a() concurrently? - i.e. I cannot rely on just calling all my CUDA kernels and only syncing at the very end)

***edit: adding to this question, to ensure it is clear enough..***

The c++ function call_cuda_fn_x() is of the form, e.g.:

```
void call_cuda_fn_x(){
    .... //some c++ working
    convolve<<<n_blocks, n_threads, n_floats*sizeof(float)>>>
        (mat1, mat2, .. );
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaThreadSynchronize());  //Wait for the GPU work to finish, BEFORE calling the next CUDA code.

    mat_mul<<<n_blocks, n_threads, n_floats*sizeof(float)>>>
        (mat1, mat2, .. );
    CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaThreadSynchronize());  //Wait for the GPU work to finish.
    .... //some more c++ working
}
```

Note the need for me to call cudaThreadSynchronize()  within this c++ function.

Comment: Have you read the [requirements](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#conurrent-kernel-execution) for concurrent kernel execution, or studied the [concurrent kernels sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#concurrent-kernels)?

Comment: Robert - thanks for those. Very useful.  So GTX680 can run concurrent kernels - good.  And (as I understand it) in cases where my c++ functions do not depend on the results of the CUDA code (i.e. no "if(cuda_answer>0.0){ ... }"), I can concurrently run several streams, each of which runs its code sequentially, all called from the same cpu thread - also good.  Where the c++ code depends on cuda results, I'm still not sure what to do - but I'm about halfway there now :)  Thanks.

Comment: If host code depends on cuda results, then you will (presumably) need to copy the cuda results from device to host.  Issue the device to host `cudaMemcpyAsync` for those results *into the same stream* where the kernel generating those results was launched.  Then issue a `cudaStreamSynchronize` for that stream, prior to any usage of that data in host code.  Concurrent kernel execution may be easier to achieve/observe on linux instead of windows (WDDM) for a variety of reasons

Answer (score -1):

Kernel calls are asynchronous from the point of view of the CPU so if you call 2 kernels in succession the second one will be called without waiting for the first one to finish. It only means that the control returns to the CPU immediately.

So, you can launch in the following sequence.

```
fn_1()
cudaEventSynchronize()
fn_2()
fn_a()
cudaEventSynchronize()
fn_b()
fn_3()
cudaEventSynchronize()
fn_c()
```

Comment: Thanks Itachi.  But inside fn_2() I have several cudaThreadSynchronize() calls.  (I have to have this, because the kernel calls inside fn_2() need to be sequential).  Doesn't that mean that my c++ thread hangs at the cudaThreadSynchronize() call?

Comment: Kernel calls inside fn_2() ? Are you launching more kernels from fn_2() using Dynamaic Parallelsim ?

Comment: fn_2() calls other c++ functions:  call_cuda_fn_x(); and call_cuda_fn_y();   They call CUDA code e.g. like so: mat_mul<<<n_blocks, n_threads, n_floats*sizeof(float)>>>(arg1, arg2);  
CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(cudaThreadSynchronize());    - where mat_mul is \_\_global\_\_

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. `__syncthreads()` synchronizes threads inside the kernel. `cudaEventSynchronize()` synchronizes cuda events like kernel execution, etc. So, I don't see a problem here.

Comment: Sure, \_\_syncthreads() calls are fine.  But just here, I was asking about   cudaThreadSynchronize()  - I'll add to my question, to ensure it is clear enough.

Comment: This answer is lacking.  It doesn't mention that cuda calls issued to the same stream are serialized, even asynchronous calls, such as kernels.  If you don't use multiple streams to launch kernels that are intended to run concurrently, you won't have good results.